# Can you please find a way to fix this

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local tool = script.Parent
local ability = tool:GetAttribute("Ability2")

local function onActivate()
    print("Ability activated!")
    if ability == 1 then
        local pos = Vector3.new(0, 100, 0) 
        local size = Vector3.new(10, 500, 10) 
        local color = Color3.fromRGB(255, 0, 0) 
        local laserPart = Instance.new("Part")
        laserPart.Size = size
        laserPart.Color = color
        laserPart.Anchored = true
        laserPart.CanCollide = false
        laserPart.Transparency = 0.5
        laserPart.Position = pos
        laserPart.Parent = workspace

        local laserBeam = Instance.new("Beam")
        laserBeam.FaceCamera = true
        laserBeam.CurveSize0 = 0
        laserBeam.CurveSize1 = 0
        laserBeam.Texture = "rbxassetid://4406301808"
        laserBeam.Color = color
        laserBeam.LightEmission = 1
        laserBeam.Width0 = 5
        laserBeam.Width1 = 5
        laserBeam.Attachment0 = laserPart.CFrame:ToObjectSpace(CFrame.new(pos, pos + Vector3.new(0, size.Y, 0)))
        laserBeam.Attachment1 = workspace.CurrentCamera.CFrame:ToObjectSpace(CFrame.new(pos, pos + Vector3.new(0, size.Y, 0)))
        laserBeam.Parent = laserPart

        wait(5) 
        laserPart:Destroy()
    end
end

tool.Activated:Connect(activate)
```

I try for it to summon a laser down BUT it show error like nil function and cannot find the function
so I would like to know if there any error or typo in my code or any function is invalid or doesn't exist Thankyou

Comment: What *exactly* was the error message?

Comment: Attachment must be attached to base part or other attachment is the error message also im trying to fix the thing too and made a new code @InSync

Answer (score 1):

`activate` in `tool.Activated:Connect(activate)` is `nil` because you didn't defined it. Maybe you can try `tool.Activated:Connect(onActivate)`?